# CouchDB not allowing '+' in database name

Tags: couchdb

CouchDB v3.2.1 on Ubuntu 20.04.4

```
curl -X PUT https://localhost:6984/test+database --cookie 'AuthSession=<session cookie>'
```

gives the error:

```
{"error":"illegal_database_name","reason":"Name: 'test database'. Only lowercase characters (a-z), digits (0-9), and any of the characters _, $, (, ), +, -, and / are allowed. Must begin with a letter."}
```

Trying to create the database using Fauxton gives the same error.

Notice that in the error message it is changing '+' to ' '.

I've seen other questions here regarding not being able to delete a database with a '+' in the name as well. Is this a recent bug in couchdb where it no longer allows '+'?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed a `+` is a legal character for a database name according to [PUT /{db}](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/common.html#put--db):

> Creates a new database. The database name {db} must be composed by
> following next rules:
>
> - Name must begin with a lowercase letter (a-z)
> - Lowercase characters (a-z)
> - Digits (0-9)
> - Any of the characters _, $, (, ), +, -, and /.

SO to the problem at hand - simply [percent encode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) that `+`

```
curl -X PUT https://localhost:6984/test%2Bdatabase --cookie 'AuthSession=<session cookie>'
```

This is a curl thing, not a couchdb thing.

Comment: I already tried that and it gives the same error. Note that Fauxton also gives the same error -- it is not curl.

Comment: Works for me with Fauxton and bash ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯